# Como dar permissões para rodar aplicação pelo GENEXUS WEB START, WIN, GX9, JAVA ((build 1.8.0_31-b13))

Tags: genexus

alguém tem aplicação gerada pelo GX9, JAVA, WIN, e fez a atualização para a VM do JAVA ((build 1.8.0_31-b13)) ?
Conseguiram dar permissões para a aplicação ser iniciada ?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode colocar informação mais detalhada da mensagem de erro ou aviso que está recebendo?
Qual o sistema operacional?
Não ficou claro para mim se é um problema no momento de instalar a aplicação ou na hora de rodar a aplicação. Embora ache que seja na hora de rodar.

Minha ideia é conseguir mais informações para saber se o problema é relacionado a algum problema em certificado ou se é problema de permissões na máquina, como UAC, IIS, etc...

Mas acho que vale a pena você dar uma olhada no seguinte link: (olhar em espanhol, pois está mais completo)

http://www2.gxtechnical.com/portal/hgxpp001.aspx?15,4,61,O,S,0,,36829

E dê uma olhada também neste outro link (pois ainda não tenho claro qual o seu problema):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277496/registry-key-has-value-1-7-but-1-6-is-required-java-1-7-is-installed